# Dynamically redefine a function like print.data.frame

Tags: r

1. Is there a way to redefine a locked function?
2. What would be the best way to dynamically redefine such a globally available function while evaluating some code?

Example: I have the following code:

```
print(cars[1:5, ])
```

This usually calls `print.data.frame` but for whatever reasons I want it to call `my.fancy.print.data.frame()` instead. What would be the best way to achieve this?

In the end, I would like to have something like this:

```
evalWithEnvir(print(cars[1:5, ]), envir = list(print.data.frame = my.fancy.print.data.frame))
```

EDIT:
The question was badly asked. The problem was that I used `<<-` to redefine the function. This tried to set the function in the wrong environment. As @hrbrmstr pointed out below, the function can be easily redefined in the global environment.

Comment: I think that when you use a generic function like that it calls the method based on the attribute class of the object. For example in general, if the object is a data frame it calls the method `print.data.frame` and so on. One way to achieve your goal could be to define a personal class and then add a method (for that class) to the print (or whatever it is) function.

Comment: @SabDeM I have no control over the code that eventually calls `print.data.frame`. In code, I can control I call `my.fancy.print.data.frame` right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print.data.frame` is not 'locked' (or hidden). It appears among `methods("print")`, where the non-visible methods are also given.

If you prefer not to define a special `class`, you can overwrite `base::print.data.frame` in a defined environment and reference this in your code e.g.

```
e1 <- new.env(parent=.GlobalEnv)
assign("print.data.frame",
       function(x) print((unclass(x))),
       envir=e1)
with(e1, print(cars[1:5, ]))
```

giving:

```
$speed
[1] 4 4 7 7 8

$dist
[1]  2 10  4 22 16

attr(,"row.names")
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

and your other code should run as normal inside `e1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine the functionality of `print.data.frame` in your environment with:

```
print.data.frame <- function(x, ..., digits = NULL,
      quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, row.names = TRUE) {
  print("WOO HOO")
}
```

Now that's *useless* since it will just print `WOO HOO` vs do something meaningful but it should help you get started.

SabDeM's idea is a better one:

```
class(mtcars) <- c("myclass", class(mtcars))

print.myclass <- function(x) {
  print(ls.str(x))
}

print(mtcars)

## am :  num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
## carb :  num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
## cyl :  num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
## disp :  num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
## drat :  num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
## gear :  num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
## hp :  num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
## mpg :  num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
## qsec :  num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
## vs :  num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
## wt :  num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
```